# How to prevent Rubymine from automatically saving changed files on exit without any prompt?

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, rubymine

When I close Rubymine with some unsaved changed files, it saves those files automatically without any prompt. Is there anyway to disable this auto-save-on-close behavior?  I searched that huge option tree for a while but achieved nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You are welcome to join the discussion in [IDEABKL-6460](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6460)

See also http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5469319#5469319 for some tips on changing the current behavior. But note that this auto-saving is a core IDE feature so that it can't be disabled completely. Auto-save can happen at multiple stages: e.g. making changes in Settings, running command in Terminal, executing/debugging script etc.

Comment: Hopefully I faced this issue during the evaluation period of RubyMine, so I stopped using it before having lost money buying it !!

Answer (score 5):

Check here https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/saving-and-reverting-changes.html Gives instructions on how to disable this.

**To enable auto-saving on the regular basis**

1. In the Settings dialog box, expand Appearance & Behavior node, and
   click System Settings.
2. Select the check box Save files
   automatically, if the application is idle for and specify the number
   of seconds of idleness required to activate saving.

Instead of selecting the checkbox, deselect it.

Comment: Could you paste the interesting part of the document your are linking to ?